# Check if symbol is a dot char in scheme : #\.?

Tags: vector, char, scheme

Given that `myVector` is a vector and `i` is an index , when I do this :

```
(= (vector-ref myVector i) #\.)
```

I get :

```
=: contract violation
  expected: number?
  given: #\.
  argument position: 1st
  other arguments...:
   #\.
```

How can I check if the character at location `i` is a `.` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not convert the character to a number, simply use the [`char=?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/characters.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._char%7E3d%7E3f%29%29) procedure, from the documentation:

> Returns #t if all of the arguments are eqv?

For your example in particular:

```
(define myVector #(#\1 #\. #\2))
(define i 1)

(char=? (vector-ref myVector i) #\.)
=> #t
```

Several of your questions of the last couple of days have been related to character or string manipulation, I'd advise you take a good look at the documentation page dealing with [those](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/characters.html) [subjects](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html).

Comment: Guess I should have looked at the error message more carefully :) +1

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** This incorrectly assumed the vector was of number and not characters. Use Oscar's answer.

You need to convert the number to a character or viceversa.

Eg:

```
(= (vector-ref myVector i) (char->integer #\.))
```

Or

```
(char=? (integer->char (vector-ref myVector i)) #\.)
```